# Make variables from jquery function to be accessible from other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jquery function like this:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myjqfunction = function(cfg){

     var foo1, foo2; 

     return this.each...    

  };
})(jQuery);
```

How can I make foo1 and foo2 to be accessible from outside (from another function like this)?

These variables will store the state of some things that affect the entire document, and I want the other function to be aware of that...

Comment: If every function needs to know about them you should declare them globally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare them outside the function, i.e., global.

You may want to put them in a namespace/object/module to be on the safe side. Which method is best depends on what you're actually doing with them.

For example, if they're related to specific selectors, it might be "best" to attach them directly to the DOM elements using `.data`, or keep them inside another jQuery function, etc.

Comment: can I make myjqfunction the namespace ? and access them like myjqfunction.foo1 ?

Comment: I guess so, try to this.foo1; this.foo2;

Answer (score 1):

Set up your function like this:

```
(function($){
  function myjqfunction( cfg ) {
    return this.each( ... );
  }

  $.myjqfunction = {
    foo1: ... ,
    foo2: ... 
  };

  $.fn.myjqfunction = myjqfunction;
})(jQuery);
```

Then from outside your plugin, code can refer to `$.myjqfunction.foo1` to get at those variables, and you'd refer to them the same way from inside your plugin code.

There are of course other similar ways to set that up.